# Regular expression - how to match string not starting with

Tags: regex

I have the following Strings:

```
abc 12x15x2x99 31x15x29 zzz
ppp 12x52x2x69 24x05x59 mmm
12x55x2x99 2x05x90
12x55x2x99 20x05x71 zzz
pppppp 12x55x2x17 21x55x99 
21x4x23
eee 24x45x49 mmmm
```

In each row I want to find match for NNxNNxNN where NN can be one number or two numbers

I look for a string that not start and end with x and has the form NNxNNxNN

I wrote the following RegEx, but it doesn't find the required match :

```
.*[^x]?([0-9]{1,2}x[0-9]{1,2}x[0-9]{1,2}[^x]).*
```

How can I tell it to not expect the symbol x at the beginning of the match?

Comment: Maybe [just use](https://regex101.com/r/brPSTs/1) word boundary? `\b[0-9]{1,2}(?:x[0-9]{1,2}){2}\b`?

Comment: or shorter: `\b\d\d?x\d\d?x\d\d?\b`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, bobble bubble - thanks it works